# What is the relation between host.conf and resolv.conf

Tags: resolv.conf

I am using ubuntu. I see the following information from the manpage:

- For `/etc/host.conf` (`man host.conf`)

  > host.conf - resolver configuration file
  >
  > The file /etc/host.conf contains configuration information specific to the resolver library.
- For `/etc/resolv.conf` (`man resolv.conf`)

  > resolv.conf - resolver configuration file
  >
  > The  resolver  is  a  set of routines in the C library that provide access to the Internet Domain Name System (DNS).

Does the resolver use both files, in which order and what are the differences?

Comment: [Linux: Difference between /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/118923/difference-between-etc-hosts-and-etc-resolv-conf)

Comment: That question is not the same, it references /etc/hosts but this question is about /etc/host.conf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern Linux systems, the *resolver library* referred to by these man pages is integrated to the `glibc` library. The `/etc/host.conf` is read by the part integrated in the main `glibc` library: note that the man page says the current implementation only recognizes the `trim`, `multi` and `reorder` keywords, although the `Historical` paragraph in the `NOTES` section indicates there used to be more.

The actual lookups are performed by the various plug-in libraries, as determined by the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. Each lookup method, like `files`, `nis`, `dns` or `compat` has an one-to-one correspondence to a library file, like `libnss_files.so.2`, `libnss_nis.so.2`, `libnss_dns.so.2` or `libnss_compat.so.2` for example.

The plug-ins `libnss_files.so.2`, `libnss_dns.so.2`, `libnss_compat.so.2` and `libnss_hesiod.so.2` are provided with the main `glibc` library package, but there are also other plug-ins from different sources, like `libnss_nis.so.2` from a separate `libnss-nis` package, `libnss_mdns*.so.2` from the `libnss-mdns` package, and `libnss_resolve.so.2` designed to be used with `systemd-resolved`. If you integrate the system with LDAP or Active Directory, those integration solutions will also provide their own `libnss_*` libraries.

If the `hosts:` line in `nsswitch.conf` includes `dns`, then `libnss_dns.so` is used, and it will read `/etc/resolv.conf`.

But if `dns` is replaced with `resolve`, then `libnss_resolve.so.2` is used instead. This will ignore the classic `/etc/resolv.conf` and will instead talk to the `systemd-resolved` daemon, which is configured by `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file, drop-in files at `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/*.conf`, `[/usr]/lib/systemd/resolved.conf.d/*.conf` or `/run/systemd/resolved.conf.d/*.conf`, or the `resolvectl` command-line tool.

In order to also cover programs that read `/etc/resolv.conf` directly instead of using `glibc`'s resolver library (like certain versions of the `nslookup` command for example), `systemd-resolved` will (unless this feature is turned off) maintain a listener for DNS requests at 127.0.0.53 and provide a dummy `/etc/resolv.conf` pointing to it.

---

In other words: without consulting `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, you can only know for sure that `/etc/host.conf` will be used. What happens after that will depend on what `/etc/nsswitch.conf` says.

Most programs will use the hostname resolution functions of the `glibc` library, and so will use `/etc/resolv.conf` **only if** the `hosts:` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` includes the keyword `dns`.

If the `hosts:` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` includes the keyword `resolve` instead, **you should treat `/etc/resolv.conf` as legacy**  and use the `resolvectl` command to check the actual DNS server configuration. In this case, `/etc/resolv.conf` only exists to guide those few programs that use their own DNS resolution functions to use the services of the local `systemd-resolved`, which will then forward their requests to the actual DNS servers (or provide an answer based on MDNS or LLMNR, if the request is about a local network service and MDNS/LLMNR information is available).

Comment: thanks very much for this detailed explaination. Can I summarize it as follows: `host.conf` is always used by `glibc`. `resolv.conf` is used by `hosts: dns`. `hosts: resolve` also uses `resolv.conf` but it is only to redirect the user to `127.0.0.53`, where `systemd-resolved` works as an agent. The behavior of `systemd-resolved` is controlled by `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

Comment: That's a good summary.

Comment: I feel the above summary might be slightly wrong. Is this more correct: `host.conf` is always used by `glibc`. `resolv.conf` is used by `hosts: dns`. Usually it is to direct the user to `127.0.0.53`, where `systemd-resolved` works as an agent. The behavior of `systemd-resolved` is controlled by `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. If `hosts: resolve` is used instead of `hosts: dns`, `resolve.conf` is not checked. The name lookup requests directly go to `systemd-resolved`.   (From above: I feel that `hosts: dns` and `hosts: resolve` will both reach `systemd-resolved` at the end)

Comment: I'd say: first look into `nsswitch.conf`. If it says `hosts: dns`, then look at `resolv.conf`. It may specify either real DNS server(s) or forwarder(s). If it says `nameserver 127.0.0.53`, do as if `nsswitch.conf` had said `hosts: resolve`. If `nsswitch.conf` says `hosts: resolve`, skip `resolv.conf` altogether and just use the `resolvectl` tool and the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file.